# Sort excel table (multiple columns) by numeric column

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, sorting

I have this table from program profiling:

[image: image description]

I need to sort it by **Total** column. But instead, the Excel sorts the numbers *alphabetically*. I can't even believe it's that stupid. Just check it out!

[image: image description]

Of course, the cells in same rows must all be sorted. How do I do this?

Comment: Make sure your column is formatted as a number or general and not text.

Comment: And how can I mass convert the cells to text?

Comment: *to a number (not converting to text, you don't want it as text!)

Comment: Select the column, right click, goto format, select numeric or general, NOT text

Comment: Sorry, I meant text. I selected number but it still acts as text. I assume this is because in Czech typography, `,` is used to delimit decimal places, not `.`. I didn't notice that before.

Comment: Yes that would cause it to not sort properly. Did it work  when you changed it to "."?

Answer (score 0):

To convert a range of numbers stored as text to numbers do this:

- type `0` in an empty cell, then select it and press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>
- select the range you want to convert
- select: home - paste - paste special - add - ok

(you can also multiply by 1).

After converting, your short will work as expected (also rows will be moved together by default).

### Update

of course, your original text formatting should match regional number format, if not, then you need to fix it (select range and use find - replace) before

Comment: The trick with addition doesn't work unfortunatelly. I ended up using <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>H</hbd> and replacing letters.